# How to access Babel generated classes externally, e.g. in HTML source?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, babeljs

Using Babel and Webpack I generated a number of ES6 classes that I want to call up in my HTML. The problem is that when I try to use these classes in my HTML source, I end up with identifier not defined error. How can Babel+Webpack generated classes, variables, etc. be accessed externally?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a novice with Babel and Webpack, and I found very little in my search that helped with this problem. Here's what I found by trial and error works for me:

I have source files like A_src.js:

```
let A_var = 123;
class A_Cls { ... }
export { A_Cls, A_var }  // the export statement to vital
```

In my webpack.config.js I have:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    entry: {
        ...
        A_src: './src/A_src.js',
        B_src: './src/B_src.js',
        ...
    },
    ,output: {
        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'build' ),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        pathinfo: true
    }
```

I found that to access the Babel+Webpack generated classes, I had to do this in my HTML:

```
<!-- load the generated bundle -->
<script type="text/javascrip" src="app_bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascrip">
    var html_var = A_src.A_var + 123;
    var A_Obj = new A_src.A_Cls();
</script>
```

Hopefully, this helps. If anyone has a better method and better explanation, I'd appreciate your feedback.